# Setting up Wordpress Multi-site on IIS7 with domains

Tags: wordpress

I am having difficulty with my domain mapping on Wordpress with Networking enabled and using the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin. I am running everything on a Windows 2008 server using IIS7. I have the domains mapped and my domain host DNS settings are correct. The domains go to my server IP.

I have created multiple sites and can edit them via the dashboard but when I click on the view site link I to the default web page for IIS.

Do I need to set up something in IIS? I don't understand how the domains are supposed to resolve to the correct Wordpress site. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know IIS, but you have to make sure that the DocumentRoot of all domains point to the wordpress installation dir.

Comment: That makes sense. However, if I browse locally on the server (via remote client) the domains are mapped correctly - that is I am taken to the proper site in WP. Although it gives me a page not found error... I tried setting the domain on the Wordpress directory but I still don't get to the site from my desktop.

Comment: is there an "official" web.config set of rules for IIS? I see this one  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-on-iis but it's a couple of years old.